# This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= when I use subquery

Tags: sql-server-2012, subquery

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN AT_EMPSCHEDULE.START1 <> '01/01/1900' 
            AND AT_EMPSCHEDULE.START2 <> '01/01/1900' 
            AND AT_EMPSCHEDULE.END2 <> '01/01/1900'
            AND AT_EMPSCHEDULE.LEAVECODE ='' 
            AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT PDATE 
                           FROM HR_PUBHOLIDAY 
                           WHERE PDATE=AT_EMPSCHEDULE.TRANDATE) 
            AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,AT_EMPSCHEDULE.TRANDATE) <> 1 
          THEN 
             CAST((SELECT HIS_GENSALARYD.BASESALARY/HIS_GENSALARYD.WORKDAY 
                   FROM HIS_GENSALARYD 
                   WHERE (AT_EMPSCHEDULE.TRANDATE BETWEEN HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYFROM 
                                                  AND HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYTO 
                     AND HIS_GENSALARYD.EMPCODE = AT_EMPSCHEDULE.EMPCODE)) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS DAILYSALARY
FROM 
    HIS_GENSALARY 
INNER JOIN 
    AT_EMPSCHEDULE ON HIS_GENSALARY.EMPCODE = AT_EMPSCHEDULE.EMPCODE 
                   AND MONTH(TRANDATE) = HIS_GENSALARY.INMONTH 
                   AND YEAR(TRANDATE) = HIS_GENSALARY.INYEAR 
WHERE 
    HIS_GENSALARY.EMPCODE = HIS_GENSALARY.EMPCODE
```

I get the message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: In the context its used, the subquery can return at most one row. SQL Server is expecting a scalar value. A single value. Not a resultset,  The observed behavior is expected, and consistent with documented behavior.  Was there a *question*? Maybe you want to return a single value, for example, by using an aggregate function such as AVG?  We're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
(SELECT HIS_GENSALARYD.BASESALARY/HIS_GENSALARYD.WORKDAY 
 FROM HIS_GENSALARYD 
 WHERE AT_EMPSCHEDULE.TRANDATE BETWEEN HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYFROM 
     AND HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYTO 
 AND HIS_GENSALARYD.EMPCODE = AT_EMPSCHEDULE.EMPCODE)
```

that you have used as an expression. As per the error message, it must only *ever* produce *one* result where you have used it; ie it must never return more than one row, but at least one invocation has returned multiple rows.

To force it to only ever return one row, apply an aggregate function to it; an obvious choice is `max()`:

```
(SELECT MAX(HIS_GENSALARYD.BASESALARY/HIS_GENSALARYD.WORKDAY)
 FROM HIS_GENSALARYD 
 WHERE AT_EMPSCHEDULE.TRANDATE BETWEEN HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYFROM 
     AND HIS_GENSALARYD.PAYTO 
 AND HIS_GENSALARYD.EMPCODE = AT_EMPSCHEDULE.EMPCODE)
```